# Advantage of using Ubuntu Enterprise Cloud (UEC) compared to VMWare?

Tags: ubuntu, vmware-vsphere, ubuntu-enterprise-cloud, uec

I intend to do some virtualization with either of the two technologies: Ubuntu Enterprise Cloud and VMWare.

I would like to know the advantages (e.g. main features missing in the other one, long-run, financial advantages, support...) of using the **Ubuntu Enterprise cloud** compared to **VMWare**.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UEC does employ KVM virtualization however! I would think VMware's best competitive advantage is the availability of mature GUI management tools, and UEC's best competitive advantage is being open-source, and providing a compatible EC2 API interface

Answer (score 1):

UEC is not a visualization suite. VMWare is.

http://www.ubuntu.com/cloud

UEC allows you to creates a cluster of machines and distribute load across them.
VMWare allows you to create virtual machines to take advantage of powerful hardware.